# MySQL Subquery with Averages From Another Table

Tags: mysql, average

I'm sure this has been answered, but for the life of me I couldn't find the answer.

If I have two tables (gre_words and gre_link).  The grey_words table has columns (id, word, definition) and the gre_link table has columns (word_id, difficulty).

Basically, after each question, an entry goes into gre_link with the word's id and a difficulty (0 if correct, 1 if wrong).

So I now want to generate a list of the top 5 hardest words.

I think I need a MySQL SELECT statement with a nested statement with the AVG() function on the difficulty column.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct I think that you just need to do a join and apply the `avg` function and limit the result to the 5 lowest averages so this might be what you want:

```
select 
    w.word, avg(l.difficulty * 1.0) average_correct
from 
    gre_words w
join 
    gre_link l on w.id = l.word_id
group by 
    w.word
order by 
    avg(l.difficulty * 1.0)
limit 5
```

Note that this excludes words in the gre_words table that doesn't have any corresponding rows in the gre_link table.